# Odd behaviour in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im a bit new to **MVC** and Im no experienced coder so I might have missed something really obvious.

I have tried searching for relevant info but have come up with nothing explaining the strange sudden change in behavior.

I have a *TestApp* which calls a **MVC application** using `HTTPClient.GetAsync`.

I put a breakpoint like this in TestApp:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(${GetApiUrl(ApiUrls.GetOrder)}?OrderRef{Order.OrderRef}");
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); <<< Breakpoint
```

Basically what happens once the `await client.GetAsync(...` executes is that VS2015 just waits forever and the call never returns to the debugger?

For your information I also have a **breakpoint** set on the **MVC** side looking like this:

```
[Route("Order")]
[HttpGet]
public Order GetOrder(string OrderRef)
{ <<< Breakpoint
```

This **breakpoint** is never hit, I have configured the solution to start multiple project the *TestApp* and the **MVC** projects.

The thing is that this was working just a day ago, no changes have been made but almost like the **debugger** just decided to go to bed.

However I also checked the **IIS Express TraceFiles** and there I can see the request completing:

```
GENERAL_ENDPOINT_INFORMATION RemoteAddress="::1", RemotePort="51697", LocalAddress="::1", LocalPort="7368" 08:21:39.381
GENERAL_REQUEST_HEADERS Headers="Connection: Keep-Alive Host: localhost:7368" 08:21:39.381 
URL_CACHE_ACCESS_START RequestURL="/api/Order?OrderRef=230" 08:21:39.381 
URL_CACHE_ACCESS_END PhysicalPath="", URLInfoFromCache="false", URLInfoAddedToCache="true", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)" 08:21:39.381
```

Why I cant debug **MVC** calls anymore or even execute them it beyond me, as I mentioned this worked a day ago and the only code I have changed since then what I can recall is the code outside this method making the `GetAsync call`

I would be really grateful for any help on this!

Regards,
Claudio

Here is the whole chain of code hope this helps:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task DoWorkImportExport1()
{
     GetOrders().Wait();

  private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task GetOrders()
  {
       Order objVismaOrder = await GetOrder(o);

    private async Task<Order> GetOrder(Order Order)
    { 
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{GetApiUrl(ApiUrls.GetOrder)}?OrderRef={Order.OrderRef}");
```

Comment: If you put the url in the browser does it load the resource?

Comment: Are you using the *Debug* configuration?   Have you tried a Clean and Rebuild?

Comment: It sounds like a classic deadlock but you haven't posted enough code for us to see it. Do you do any blocking of async calls anywhere up to calling the code you have shown? Like with `.Result`?

Comment: Please look above for calling methods before the call that get stuck!